# Debugging hackerrank week of code 25: Between two sets

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, factors

I have a problem on hackerrank as below.
My answer is after this problem description, it shows ok after running the code, but then when I submit the code, this code only passes 3 per 6 test cases. I still not figure out where is my mistake. Any helps would be very appreciated. Thanks.

> Consider two sets of positive integers, A={a0, a1, ..., a(n-1)} and B={b0, b1, ..., b(m-1)} . We say that a positive
>   integer, x, is between sets A and B if the following conditions are
>   satisfied:
>
> All elements in A are factors of x. And x is a factor of all elements in B.
>   Given A and B, find and print the number of integers (i.e., possible 's)
>   that are between the two sets.
>
> Input Format
>
> The first line contains two space-separated integers describing the
>   respective values of n (the number of elements in set A) and m (the
>   number of elements in set B).  The second line contains  distinct
>   space-separated integers describing a0, a1, ..., a(n-1). The third line contains 
>   distinct space-separated integers describing b0, b1, ..., b(m-1).
>
> Constraints
>
> 1<= n, m <= 10
>
> 1<= a(i) <= 100
>
> 1<= b(i) <= 100
>
> Output Format
>
> Print the number of integers that are considered to be between A and B.
>
> Sample Input
>
> 2 3
>
> 2 4
>
> 16 32 96
>
> Sample Output
>
> 3
>
> Explanation
>
> The integers that are between A={2, 4} and B={16, 32, 96} are 4, 8, and 16.

My code:

```
public class Solution {
    public static boolean checkX_function(int Ax, int [] b){
        for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++){
            if(b[i]%Ax!=0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt(); // n: length of array A
        int m = in.nextInt(); // m: length of array B
        int[] a = new int[n];
        for(int a_i=0; a_i < n; a_i++){
            a[a_i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        int[] b = new int[m];
        for(int b_i=0; b_i < m; b_i++){
            b[b_i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        boolean checkX = false;
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){            
            for(int j=i; j<n; j++){
                int Ax = 0;
                Ax = a[i]*a[j];
                //check if Ax is satisfied for all elements in B
                checkX = checkX_function(Ax, b);
                if (checkX == true){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm is looking only for `a[i]*a[j] is_factor_of b[1..m]`, whereas the problem is find `x` where `a[1..m] is_factor_of x AND x is_factor_of b[1..m]`. BTW, I think the correct answer (after checking `a[1..n] is_factor_of max(a)` and `min(b) is_factor_of b[1..n]`) is `for(i=max(a); i < min(b); i *= LCM(a)) if (i is_factor_of b[1..m]) ++count;` or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look

```
int main(){
    int n;
    int m;
    int currentNum,count=0 ;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for(int a_i = 0;a_i < n;a_i++){
       cin >> a[a_i];
    }
    vector<int> b(m);
    for(int b_i = 0;b_i < m;b_i++){
       cin >> b[b_i];
    }
    currentNum = a[n-1];

    do{   

         bool check1 = true;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(currentNum%a[i]!=0){
                check1 = false;
            }
        }

        if(check1){


        bool check = true;
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            if(b[i]%currentNum!=0){
                check = false;
            }
        }
        if(check){

     //   cout<<currentNum<<"\n";
            count++;
        }
        }
        currentNum ++;

    }while(currentNum <=b[0]);

    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi have written the below code and it's passed all the test cases.

```js
function getTotalX(a, b) {
    // Write your code here
    let counter = 0;
    for (let currentNum = 0; currentNum <= 100; currentNum++) {
        let check1 = true;
        for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (currentNum % a[j] != 0) {
                check1 = false;
            }
        }
        if (check1) {
            let checkx = checkFactor(currentNum, b);
            if (checkx) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

function checkFactor(ax, b) {
    for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if (b[i] % ax != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getTotalX(a, b):
   def factor(x,y):
      return x%y==0

   list1=[]
   for i in range(max(a),min(b)+1):
       if all(factor(i,x) for x in a) and all(factor(x,i) for x in b):
          list1.append(i) 


   return len(list1)
```

Comment: To me, this code looks a lot more like Python than Java.

Comment: @AdrianMole, the other answers are in C and JavaScript